# Python Selenium Web Table Scraping issue

Tags: python, pandas, selenium-webdriver

I am learning Python with Selenium. In this learning I am trying to open Google Finance and scrape Quarterly Financial Table with Data. Eventually my target is to read the ticker from a table column and scrape data from the Quarterly Financial table.

While testing, I found capturing all the rows are little challenging for me. Can you please take a look at the code and let me know what I am doing wrong here?

Also if someone can help me how can I use Xpath here instead of CSS locators that will be very helpful.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd
import time

pages = 3
url = 'https://www.google.com/finance'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

def getData(start_url, pgs):
    current = 0
    urls = driver.get(start_url)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='lst-ib']").send_keys("F")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@name='btnG']").click()
    data = {}
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Title','Sep 2019', 'Y/Y'])

    myTable = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.mMbopd')
    dataLength = len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('td.kyITtb'))
    for allData in myTable:
        print(dataLength)

        for scrpe in allData.find_elements_by_css_selector('table.iF8z4d'):
            for i in range(dataLength):
                data['Title'] = scrpe.find_elements_by_css_selector('td.kyITtb')[current].text
                data['Sep 2019'] = scrpe.find_elements_by_css_selector('td.efHLT.ckQqBf') [current].text
                data['Y/Y'] = scrpe.find_elements_by_css_selector('td.Mk9Auc.ckQqBf')[current].text
                df = df.append(data, ignore_index=True)
        current +=1

    return df

getData(url, pages).to_excel(r'Learn Scraping\first_file.xlsx')
driver.close()
```

Comment: if css selector works then why to use xpath?

Comment: what do you expect with `send_keys("F")` ? If I run it then Google shows that there is data for symbol `F` and it shows empty page. Maybe you should skip it or use different symbol.

Comment: with Google can be other problem - it has big money to create more restricted system which recognize bots/scripts and to stop getting data. For example: everytime when you load the same page it can use use different classes in same tags. Maybe find other page for learning - ie. [ToScrape.com](http://toscrape.com/) created by authors of Python module [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/). OR check if there is no API for these data.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm not giving you a solution, but if you accept a suggestion for web scraping I would use [`requests`](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) for retrieving the data and [`lxml`](https://lxml.de/index.html) or [`BeatifulSoup`](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) for the data extraction.

It is a more minimalist approach, both libraries are very well documented, there are plenty of examples, and in the end, you will get also better performance.

Just one thing: browsers generally apport changes to the code they get from the server, while with `requests` you will get exactly the code as it is. This may lead to problems and errors if you use web developer tools from browser to look at the code, since they present you the version they preprocessed. I suggest you to download the page with requests and to analyze it offline, with a text editor.

Answer (score 0):

Google is not good for start. It can use different class names on the same page in different moment. It can display different content for different users. And it can recognize script/bot and show captcha.

This code gives me some values from page but it may not work if Google display different content for you. I don't uses class names if it looks strange - when it is string with random chars and numbers.

I have to add `try/except` because Google shows me another table which has different fields then I expect.

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://www.google.com/finance'
#driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get(url)

all_tables = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.mod')

for table in all_tables[1:]:
    print('====== TABLE ======')
    try:
        for item in table.find_elements_by_css_selector('a'):
            divs = item.find_elements_by_css_selector('div > div > div')
            spans = item.find_elements_by_css_selector('div > div > span')

            symbol = divs[0]
            volume = spans[0] 
            name = spans[1] 
            price = spans[2]

            print('Symbol:', symbol.text)
            print('Volume:', volume.text)
            print('Name:', name.text)
            print('Price:', price.text)

            print('---')
    except Exception as ex:
        print('EX:', ex)
```

Result:

```
====== TABLE ======
Symbol: .DJI
Volume: 28 015,06
Name: Dow Jones Industrial Average
Price: +337,27 (1,22%)
---
Symbol: .INX
Volume: 3 145,91
Name: S&P 500 Index
Price: +28,48 (0,91%)
---
Symbol: .IXIC
Volume: 8 656,53
Name: Nasdaq Composite
Price: +85,83 (1,00%)
---
Symbol: RUT
Volume: 1 633,84
Name: Russell 2000 Index
Price: +19,00 (1,18%)
---
====== TABLE ======
Symbol: .DJI
Volume: 28 015,06
Name: Dow Jones Industrial Average
Price: +337,27 (1,22%)
---
Symbol: DAX
Volume: 13 166,58
Name: DAX PERFORMANCE-INDEX
Price: +111,78 (0,86%)
---
Symbol: SENSEX
Volume: 40 445,15
Name: BSE SENSEX
Price: −334,44 (0,82%)
---
Symbol: UKX
Volume: 7 239,66
Name: FTSE 100 Index
Price: +101,81 (1,43%)
---
Symbol: IB
Volume: 9 382,70
Name: IBEX 35
Price: +139,30 (1,51%)
---
====== TABLE ======
Symbol: EUR / USD
Volume: 1,11
Name: 00:26 UTC
Price: −0,00015 (0,014%)
---
Symbol: USD / JPY
Volume: 108,57
Name: 00:26 UTC
Price: −0,052 (0,048%)
---
Symbol: GBP / USD
Volume: 1,31
Name: 00:27 UTC
Price: +0,0011 (0,081%)
---
Symbol: USD / CAD
Volume: 1,33
Name: 00:26 UTC
Price: +0,00053 (0,040%)
---
Symbol: USD / HKD
Volume: 7,83
Name: 00:26 UTC
Price: −0,000030 (0,00038%)
---
Symbol: USD / CNY
Volume: 7,04
Name: 09:48 UTC
Price: 0,00 (0,00%)
---
Symbol: AUD / USD
Volume: 0,68
Name: 00:27 UTC
Price: −0,000073 (0,011%)
```

And here is what I see in browser on page https://www.google.com/finance

If I tried to search `F` as you try in code then I get page without any information.

[image]